# Java mail is there a better way to read emails?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have some code to read people's inbox, with a filter on send TO or FROM. The time it takes to make it process the messages is far too long.

The search term filters my total emails down to 6 emails from a specific sender, yet to process the emails it takes 4 seconds to create my email objects. I'm wondering if there is a better / faster way to do this. since I want to use this for more than just 6 emails. I'm using imaps settings with user and password to authenticate.

```
 public static List<Email> readBox(String host, String user, String pass, String protocol, String port,String downloadDir,String checksubject,String checkatt,List<String> checkfromemail,List<String> checktoemail,String mailFolder) throws Exception {
      int iport = 0;
      StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
      stopwatch.start();
      try{
          iport = Integer.parseInt(port.trim());
      }catch(Exception e){}
      List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();
    
      Properties props = new Properties();
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
    
      
      URLName urln = new URLName(protocol, host, iport, null, user, pass);
      Store store = session.getStore(urln);
      store.connect(host, user, pass);
    
      Folder folder = store.getFolder(mailFolder);
      folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
      try {
          OrTerm orTerms = null;
          SearchTerm terms = null;
          if(checkfromemail.size()>0) {
              SearchTerm [] search = new SearchTerm[checkfromemail.size()];
              for(int j = 0; j < checkfromemail.size(); j++) {
                  search[j] =  new FromStringTerm(checkfromemail.get(j).trim());
              }
              orTerms = new OrTerm(search);
          }
          if(checktoemail.size() > 0) {
              SearchTerm [] search = new SearchTerm[checktoemail.size()];
              for(int j = 0; j < checktoemail.size(); j++) {
                  search[j] =  new RecipientStringTerm(Message.RecipientType.TO, checktoemail.get(0).trim());
              }
              orTerms = new OrTerm(search);
          }
          
          if(orTerms != null) {
              emails = readInboxMailBox(folder.search(orTerms),downloadDir,checksubject,checkatt,checkfromemail,checktoemail,false,-1);
          }else {
              emails = readInboxMailBox(folder.getMessages(),downloadDir,checksubject,checkatt,checkfromemail,checktoemail,false,-1);
          }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         throw e;
      }finally {     
          folder.close(false);
          store.close();
      }
      stopwatch.stop();
      System.out.println("readed emails in " + stopwatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " miliseconds ");

      return emails;
}


private static List<Email> readInboxMailBox(Message[] messages,String downloadDir,String checksubject,String checkatt,List<String> checkfromemail,List<String> checkmailto,boolean delete,int numberOfMessages) {
     List<Email> emails = new ArrayList<Email>();
     StopWatch stopwatch = new StopWatch();
      stopwatch.start();
      
     try {
           // Get directory listing
           for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        
            // get last message
            if(numberOfMessages > 0) {
                if(i < ( messages.length - numberOfMessages)) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            Email email = new Email();
        
            // from 
            email.from = messages[i].getFrom()[0].toString();
        
            // cc list
            Address[] toArray = null;
            try {
                toArray = messages[i].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO);
            } catch (Exception e) { toArray = null; }
            if (toArray != null) {
             for (Address to : toArray) {
              email.to.add(to.toString());
             }
            }
        
            // cc list
            Address[] ccArray = null;
            try {
             ccArray = messages[i].getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC);
            } catch (Exception e) { ccArray = null; }
            if (ccArray != null) {
             for (Address c : ccArray) {
              email.cc.add(c.toString());
             }
            }
        
            // subject
            email.subject = messages[i].getSubject();
            if(!checksubject.trim().equals("")) {
                if(!email.subject.toLowerCase().contains(checksubject.toLowerCase().trim())) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        
            // received date
            if (messages[i].getReceivedDate() != null) {
             email.received = messages[i].getReceivedDate();
            } else {
             email.received = new Date();
            }
        
            // body and attachments
            email.body = "";
            Object content = messages[i].getContent();
            if (content instanceof java.lang.String) {
        
                email.body = (String) content;
        
            } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {
        
             Multipart mp = (Multipart) content;
        
             for (int j = 0; j < mp.getCount(); j++) {
        
              Part part = mp.getBodyPart(j);
              String disposition = part.getDisposition();
        
              if (disposition == null) {
        
               MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart) part;
               if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain") || mbp.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                // Plain
                email.body += (String) mbp.getContent();
               }
               else if (mbp.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
                    MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) mbp.getContent();
                    try {
                        email.body += getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
                    }catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        
              } 
              
              
//            else if ((disposition != null) && (disposition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT) || disposition.equalsIgnoreCase(Part.INLINE))) {
//      
//              if(decodeName(part.getFileName()).trim().endsWith(".vcf")){
//                  continue;
//              }
//              if(!checkatt.trim().equals("")) {
//                  String checkfile = decodeName(part.getFileName()).trim();
//                  if(!isFileMatchTargetFilePattern(checkfile,checkatt.trim())){
//                      continue;
//                  }
//              }
//              EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
//           
//              attachment.name = saveName(decodeName(part.getFileName()));
//              File savedir = new File(downloadDir);
//              savedir.mkdirs();
//              File savefile = new File(downloadDir,attachment.name);
//              String path = STR.Replace(savefile.getAbsolutePath(),attachment.name,"");
//              attachment.path = path;
//              attachment.size = saveFile(savefile, part);
//              email.attachments.add(attachment);
//              
//            }
             } // end of multipart for loop 
            } // end messages for loop
        
            if(!checkatt.trim().equals("")) {
                if(email.attachments.size()<=0) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            emails.add(email);
        
            // Finally delete the message from the server.
            if(delete) {
                messages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.DELETED, true);
            }else {
                //messages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
            }
           }
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }finally {
      }
      stopwatch.stop();
      System.out.println("processed emails in " + stopwatch.getTotalTimeMillis() + " miliseconds ");
     return emails;
 }

    private static String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException{
        String result = "";
        int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
            if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
                break; // without break same text appears twice in my tests
            } else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
                String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
                result = result + "\n" + org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
            } else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart){
                result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: What is taking 6 seconds, is that include the search, or just processing the messages? Searching can take quite a bit of time.

Comment: it is purely the processing, the searching only takes about 400 miliseconds. the processing takes 4414 miliseconds.

i just found that the messages you get from getMessages() or .search() are basically empty references that get filled when you call the needed field, so i'm looking if i can't just fetch all data directly before starting to process them.

Comment: You could try setting `mail.imap.partialfetch` to false (or as you're using imaps, `mail.imaps.partialfetch`)

Comment: I tried fetching parts of the message using fetchprofile, and it seems to work for small number of messages. But with over 50 emails it becomes slow again, so i might have to look for another approach, thanks for the comments i'll try it out.